# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') but split is not called other than in mongoose package

Tags: mongoose, next.js

Project is a next js application with a mongodb database.
Have deployed on Vercel and everything was going fine till I started adding translations with the help of next-i18next. I kept getting the mongoose error so I focused on that. So I went with a completely different database. But the error persisted.

the error is as follows:

```
    Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Call Stack
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (220:268)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (220:331)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1012:0)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1009:0)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (308:1393)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (425:34)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (756:0)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (973:1692)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (977:72)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
Object.eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (973:244)
r
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:347)
eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:1150)
eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:1168)
eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:64)
eval
node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js (1:196)
./node_modules/mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js
file:///...site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3283:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./utils/db.js (4:66)
./utils/db.js
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3774:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///.../.site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./utils/error.js (8:61)
./utils/error.js
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3785:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/pj/homi/dev/playground/bugs/homi.site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./components/listing/GoogleMapHomi.js (13:70)
./components/listing/GoogleMapHomi.js
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3532:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/pj/homi/dev/playground/bugs/homi.site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./components/listing/ListingParent.js (13:72)
./components/listing/ListingParent.js
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3576:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/pj/homi/dev/playground/bugs/homi.site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./pages/property/rent/[id].js (11:91)
./pages/property/rent/[id].js
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/pages/property/rent/%5Bid%5D.js (3741:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (618:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///.../site/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (287:21)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2Fproperty%2Frent%2F%5Bid%5D&absolutePagePath=2Fsite%2Fpages%2Fproperty%2Frent%2F%5Bid%5D.js! (5:15)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js (236:50)
```

I do not call split anywhere in the code, and I tried moving to a different model provider, other than mongoose that is. But the error keeps coming up.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

My dependencies are as follows:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.6",
    "@mapbox/node-pre-gyp": "^1.0.9",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.70",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "create-emotion-server": "^11.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "markdown-it": "^12.3.2",
    "material-ui-phone-number": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.11",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.5.0",
    "next-connect": "^0.12.2",
    "next-i18next": "^11.3.0",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "notistack": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.0",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.3.2",
    "react-social-login-buttons": "^3.6.0",
    "simple-react-lightbox": "^3.6.9-0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an error.js file comment or remove imports, and check if that helps

Comment: I figured it out a few days ago but thank you. something so small and now that I look at your answer and the error it seems so clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? I am having the same error and am not sure how to fix it.